# How to change the order of the legend of geom_rects in a ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a plot using the `geom_rect()` geometry from the `ggplot2` package.

Here is my MWE:

```
library(tidyverse)

groups = tribble(
    ~size, ~income,
    10, 400,
    60, 500,
    20, 600
)
heights = c("Height <= 60 Inches",
            "Height 61-70 Inches",
            "Height >= 71 Inches")

g = ggplot()
g = g + geom_rect(aes(xmin = 0, 
                      ymin = 0,
                      xmax = groups$size[1],
                      ymax = groups$income[1],
                      fill = heights[1]))
g = g + geom_rect(aes(xmin = groups$size[1],
                      ymin = 0,
                      xmax = sum(groups$size[1:2]),
                      ymax = groups$income[2],
                      fill = heights[2]))
g = g + geom_rect(aes(xmin = sum(groups$size[1:2]),
                      ymin = 0,
                      xmax = sum(groups$size[1:3]),
                      ymax = groups$income[3],
                      fill = heights[3]))
g = g + labs(fill = 'People Groups')
```

And the output is shown here:
[image: output of code]

I am happy with how the rectangles are drawn on the plot,
however, I am unhappy with how the order of the fills is messed up.

**How do I change the order of the fills to:
"Height <= 60 Inches", "Height 61-70 Inches", "Height >= 71 Inches"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `breaks` argument in [`scale_fill_discrete`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_colour_discrete.html)

```
g + scale_fill_discrete(breaks = heights)
```

[image]